# Is there any benefit to using a barrier over a semaphore?

Tags: c, windows, pthreads

**Preface:**
I'm maintaining some code in a library that currently uses a cross-platform implementation of semaphores to sync a few threads one time at the beginning of the program. The semaphore implementation is a thin wrapper around the pthread library in linux and around winbase's semaphore calls in Windows. This platform agnostic code only needs to operate on those two systems.

**My conundrum:**
I would like to switch to a barrier implementation, because that's all the semaphores are being used for in this library anyway. However, in order to add this functionality, I would have to add similar platform agnostic code for a barrier. Since Windows's barrier synchronization barrier API is quite different from it's other thread-related code (mutex and semaphores), it would be a fair bit of work to translate the Windows sync code into the platform agnostic version. I would like to make the change to barriers, but if there is no benefit to using barriers then I see no reason to go through the hassle of making a new implementation for a library that already works with semaphores.

**Question:**
Is there any performance benefit (or other benefit) that using a synchronization barrier would give over using a plain old semaphore implementation?

Comment: To answer this question you need answer another one: what is better? Screwdriver or hammer? Do you know the answer? BTW I think it is some kind of homework because a very similar problem was asked a few minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69933676/guarantee-global-update-across-multiple-threads

Comment: Well, that coincidence is uncanny, but this is a personal project of mine, not a homework. Also, to address your earlier concern: yes, I understand that they're different tools, but comparing them between a screwdriver and a hammer seems unrealistic to me. A more apt comparison seems like the difference between a screwdriver and a power tool with a screwdriver head. Earlier implementations of thread synchronization didn't even include barriers because the same functionality could be achieved with semaphores. Hence why I'm asking the question, do barriers have any improvements over semaphores

Comment: @0___________ My understanding is that barriers are simply an opaque wrapper over  semaphores. However, this is at best an educated guess, and I would not be surprised if the underlying code actually did have kernel-based improvements.

Comment: And just to add proof that I'm not making up my claim on the history of barriers as a part of high-level threading APIs, you can see here https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/pthread.h.html that the barrier calls weren't added to the pthread library until issue 6 of Open Group Base Specifications, whereas the remaining pthread library was added in Issue 5. I feel like the fact that the semaphore was included in winbase.h and a barrier had to be included in a separate library in Windows speaks to the fact that the semaphore is a more fundamental implementation of syncing.